# How do I morph between unrelated meshes

Tags: animation, mesh, shape-keys

I have 5 meshes that are "unrelated" - they're reasonably complex shapes (derived from medical imagery) stored in separate files created by a 3rd party program and imported into Blender.
I would like to morph from Mesh 1 to Mesh 2, to Mesh 3, and so on.

I've seen various answers on here with "ShapeKeys", but these only appear to be for altering the same mesh manually, that's not an option here.

Is this possible in Blender, and if so how?

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is possible, but there is a way to break a shape into pieces and have those pieces "rearrange" into a new shape. The tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do0jF3zb5_U

Comment: You can use a shrinkwrap modifier to create shapekeys

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80868/transforming-morphing-one-objects-shape-into-anothers

Answer (score 2):

Is your medical imagery made only of vertex (no planes)? If this is the case, you could morph one to another by using a particle system.

1. add a particle system to each object, with the same number of particles
2. create one additional object with the same number of particles
3. add Physics > keys in the last created object's particle system, create a key for each of your medical imagery objects.

Here is a complete tutorial about this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8

Hope it helps!

Comment: depending on what kind of rendering you are looking for, you can add some cool effects with the blender IK Particle Link addon.

Comment: This method will work regardless whether mesh is made of vertices or is it filled with faces and solid. The only downside is that Keys particles do not use physics, e.g. gravity.

Comment: That's right Mr Zak, what I meant is that if the medical imagery is in vertex he/she is already open to have a vertex(/particle) styled result. If the medical imagery has planes, that result won't be the same by using particles. French-speaking Belgian, doing my best here ;)