# Transforming (morphing) one object's shape into another's

Tags: animation, objects, transforms, shape-keys

For example, I have two different objects. One cube and another- sphere. Can I somehow make cube change its shape identical to the sphere through animation? I mean I can do it manually with shape keys but is there some way to do it procedurally by just having start and final shapes even with different amount of vertices? The thing is I have two much more complex objects and transforming one into another is a hell of an ordeal.

Comment: Procedural way with shape keys for 2 objects is Join As Shapes option in the Shape Key panel (object must have the same vertex count). Cast modifier could be a way for transforming 1 object (although likely not any shape as complex ones can become a mess). One more way is with Keyed particles but that will mean breaking objects into particles obviously. It all depends on what transition are you going to with and how complex objects are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Morphing objects with different vertex count is impossible AFAIK with the blender tools, unless you use a scripting. Here's ***a temporary solution*** though. It uses a ***to sphere*** tool. 
[image]

I have three objects here with a different vertex count. I'll use a sphere as a midpoint for all transformations.
[image]

Add a *shape key* (Key 1) and set its value to *1.000*. Enter Edit Mode and use To Sphere tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>). Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>-->*Smooth Vertex*. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat it (set smoothing value to *1.000* in a *Tool Shelf*) unless the vertices are relaxed. Then repeat the *to sphere* operation.
[image]

Do the same with the other objects (every one should transform to the *sphere* of an equal size). Finally keyframe the *shape keys* values and *visibility* of the objects on a timeline.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Olav3D has a [great tutorial on transformation animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbQZLVAcqgo) using shrinkwrap modifiers:

[image: Olav3D Transformation Animation]

I asked a similar question on [Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/), [answered here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196798/24959)