# How would you go about making a model transform into another model?

Tags: animation

I understand the gist of model animations and rigs and whatnot, but say I want to make a druid-type character. It would normally be a humanoid but I'd like to make an animation that could allow it to, say, transform into a wolf. Is such an animation possible or is that something that would happen entirely in the code? I'd imagine it would require some sort of system for mapping the geometry of the humanoid model to the wolf model but I have no such knowledge.

Comment: You may do it using shape keys. Take a look at this tutorial: https://vimeo.com/16783367 and this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80868/transforming-morphing-one-objects-shape-into-anothers

Comment: @PaulGonet ok I guess this process is far easier than I ever thought, you can make an answer and I'll accept it.